# How to implement a belongstTo with cakePhp 4 with conditions and different data types

Tags: php, join, cakephp, casting, has-and-belongs-to-many

My design has two models `ModelOne` and `ModelTwo`. In `ModelOne` there is an integer field which passes as a foreign key to `ModelTwo` as a varchar.

The original implementation from a previous version (cakephp 2) of cake is as follow:

```
$this->belongsTo('ModelOne')
    ->setProperty('ModelOne')
    ->setClassName('ModelOnes')
    ->setConditions(['ModelOne.field_one::TEXT = ModelTwo.field_one AND ModelOne.field_two = ModelTwo.field_two']);
```

As you can see the cast is needed because if it is not used a data type mismatch exception is thrown.

When I use it like that an exception is thrown because it seems the function CAST is not properly used. The same happens when I pass to the `setCondition` method a `QueryExpression` resulted from using the `$query->func()->CAST(...)` function provided by ORM.

How can I solve this and specify correctly the belongsTo relation?

Thanks in advance!

I'm trying to configure properly a belongsTo relation in cakephp 4 with two different data types using datatype casting with the SQL function cast or other valid approach.

**After edit**:

```
$this->belongsTo('List')->setProperty('List')->setClassName('Lists')->setConditions(['List.code::TEXT = WhiteList.code AND List.list = WhiteList.list']);
```

Comment: Please show your actual code, substituting with dummy names can hide problems, especially in places where CakePHP's naming conventions do affect functionality! Also please show the error message and the related stacktrace (you can find it copy & paste ready in the log files).

Comment: @ndm ready, I have updated my question. it's quite similar. thanks for your comment

Comment: I'm still missing the error that is being thrown. While I can imagine what it probably is, I'd prefer to be sure so that I don't give you any wrong solutions.